# Ansible: Building a new hosts.yml file and running a new playbook

Tags: azure, ansible

I am building an automation script that builds infrastructure in Azure and then installs Confluent Kafka on top if it.  Confluent already has an Ansible playbook that I want to use: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible

My playbook builds out the Azure infrastructure (SSH tokens included), clones the Confluent Git repo, and then generates a new `hosts.yml` file with the data from the newly created Azure infrastructure. I can then call the Confluent playbook with the new inventory file and all is well.

My question is, can I do everything in one playbook?  Since I don't have control over the Confluent playbook, I will need to maintain the vars from my well-formed `hosts.yml` file. The problem I have with creating a global `hosts.yml` file that works for both playbooks is a lot of the data needed for the Confluent playbook, I won't have until the infrastructure is built.

My thoughts are, I can do one of the following:

- Execute the ansible playbook with a new shell command `ansible-playbook -i cp-ansible/hosts.yml cp-ansible/all.yml`

  - I'm assuming that I will lose all the console output if I do this
- Load the playbook and do a lot of `set_fact:` tasks
- Something creative that I can't think of

My progress is over here: https://github.com/joecoolish/kafka-infrastructure-ansible

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a single file, it might be easier to have your inventory in a directory.  Either way, you want `meta: refresh_inventory`
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html

You can also use dynamic inventory from Azure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/dynamic-inventory-configure
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.html